# What is the the color gradient at borders called?

Tags: cartography

Many paper maps have an effect around the borders where there is a gradient from the darker color of the borderline to the lighter color of the area fill. What is this effect called?

See https://www.wwu.edu/huxley/spatial/tut/cart/adobe_illustrator.htm#inset for an example.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are called "Tint Bands". Here's some tutorials on how to re-create them in GIS software:

- ArcGIS: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/03/06/quick-tint-bands/
- QGIS: http://nyalldawson.net/2014/01/qgis-two-neat-features-in-2-2/ (see "Drawing polygon borders only inside the polygon" heading
- MapBox/TileMill: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/customizing-geography-class/

Answer (score 5):

I've always heard it referred to as 'verge' http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/verge, I sit next to an old-school cartographer who has made maps using antiquated techniques (manual drafting of maps) and that's the word he uses.